# SMS Delivery Reports

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

If you sent out an SMS message from a SMS Gateway, will send it to the mobile network so how we get the perfect result for SMS delivery..? they send us the number of successfully send message but not in detail like sent Successful on this numbers and for this number are failure

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what SMS gateway you use, what destinations you send to (even within a country there are differences between operators)

You have 3 options really, and these are country/SMS route dependant:

- No DLR support
- Network DLR (so you get updates if the NETWORK has received the SMS)
- Handset DLR (you will get updates if the HANDSET has received the SMS)

The handset DLR is the most reliable, but in general, depending on DLR for delivery stats is not something you want to do too much. Operators fake these (antispam measures), SMS route suppliers sometimes fake them to be able to offer lower pricing (by not submitting 10% of the messages for example), etc.

Only way to be sure if an SMS is delivered is by using testing services.
There are a number of them around. If you use services like Messagebird or [BudgetSMS.net](https://www.budgetsms.net/sms-http-api/push-dlr/), you can get the DLR updates pushed to your server, for further processing on your end (they are linked to the sent SMS itself)